# How to resize custom (created in separate file) UIView height on the ViewController which uses it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIView (consisting of .swift and .xib files). There is a button inside of it which changes its height.

I'm using this custom UIView some of my ViewController. To do it I drag UIView on the ViewController and set its class to my custom UIView. This also allows me to use this button and "change" displayed size of my custom UIView.

However the size of UIView which contains my custom UIView doesn't change and I cannot use GMSMapView which lies under this view.

How can I solve this issue and change actual height of this view in the ViewController too?

Comment: put some code so we can help you ?

Comment: It's a part of a commercial project. So I can't put actual code here. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an outlet of a constraint from storyboard and adjust its constant-property. That will course the view to resize.

Its an unusual behavior that a view resizes itself. The SuperView or ViewController should manage things like that.

When creating an outlet of the constraint, you should consider creating the outlet within the ViewController and not within the view.